# Персонаж проваливается под текстуры в Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Здраствуйте, я делаю платформер и столкнулся с такой проблемой:

У меня есть враг, вот код

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class podvish21 : MonoBehaviour
{
   public float speed = 3.5f;
   public int positionOfPatrol;
   public Transform point;    
   Transform player;
   public float stoppingDist;
   bool chiil = false;
   bool angry = false;
   bool goback = false;
   private void Start()
   {
       player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("player").transform;

   }
   private void Update()
   {

       if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, point.position) < positionOfPatrol)
           chiil = true;
       if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) < stoppingDist)
           angry = true;

       if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) > stoppingDist)
           goback = true;

       if (chiil = true)
           Chill();

       if (angry = true)
           Angry();

       if (goback = true)
           Goback();
   }
   public void Chill()
   {
       if (transform.position.x > point.position.x + positionOfPatrol)
           moveingRight = false;
       else if (transform.position.x < point.position.x - positionOfPatrol)
           moveingRight = true;
       if (moveingRight)
           transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x + speed * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y);
       else if (moveingRight = false)
           transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x - speed * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y);
   }
   public void Angry()//метод агрессии на персонажа
   {
       transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
   }
   public void Goback()
   {
       transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, point.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
   }
}
```

Проблема в том,что он дергается и подает сквозь платформы. Я проверил колайдеры с ними все в порядке. Теги я проверил. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: закоментируйте все if в методе Update и раскоментируйте лишь один и протестируйте с одним флагом. потом лишь с другим, с третьим. Возможно где-то там пытаются выполниться несколько условий и он вы итоге разрывается

Comment: Изменение `Transform` это не движение, а телепортация и к физике не имеет никакого отношения. Используй `RigidBody` или `CharacterController`.

Answer (score 0):

Старайтесь избегать перемещения через transform, так как это телепортация, то есть ваш объект телепортруется в текстуру и потом вылазит из неё. Чтобы этого не происходило используйте физическое перемещение через rigidbody.